# array for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
resources: [{
    id: staffId[0].id,
    title: staffId[0].first_name
  },

  {
    id: staffId[1].id,
    title: staffId[1].first_name
  },
  ...
]
                                            ]
```

Please help me to Write a for-loop in javascript to display the my array.

Comment: have you tried writing it yourself? What problem did you face?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried, so we can help you with that !

Comment: Hi, consider showing us what you have tried so far so we can help you to find the problem.

Comment: go and learn some basics and then tried it .. ref.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: resources: [
                          for (var i = 0,var len = staffId.length; i < len; ++i)
                          {
                            id: staffId[i].id ,
                            title: staffId[i].first_name
                          },       ],

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Welcome to SO, @AjithSimon. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and using a [mcve] in your code that is causing the problem. Asking SO to do all the work for you doesn't help you or us.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fill `resources` with `staffId` values:

```
const resources = [];
for (let i = 0, l = staffId.length; i < l; i++) { 
  const el = staffId[i];
  resources.push({ id: el.id, title: el.first_name });
};
```